# How to print p:signature of primefaces

Tags: primefaces

https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/signature.xhtml

I'm building a form that let the user enter his signature. Once the signature is done,i want to take the print out of it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing value of p:signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42762362/storing-value-of-psignature)

Comment: As in print on the client? Print the whole page, or only a signature? Or automatically print the signature on the server? What does "take the print out of it" mean?

Comment: <p:printer target="signatureId" /> , using this we can print the panel,datatable etc  likewise am asking for p:signature

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create an id for the signature and then use the following code to print it.

```
<p:printer target="signatureId" />
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work , only border is visible and signature is missing!