# Smaller display of p:signature

Tags: jsf, primefaces, digital-signature

According to [this](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/signature.xhtml) article, the basics works fine, but I'm trying to display PrimeFaces p:signature SMALLER like this:

[image] ---> [image]

When I try simply change `width` and `height` of signature (in CSS or directly like attribute of signature component), it displays small signature component, but the signature itself it's still the same size, so it's not displayed, or part of it only:

[image]

I suppose it's because the signature is stored in absolute dimensions..

How to display the stored signature smaller?

**SVG:** 
According [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42762362/how-to-convert-psignature-value-to-an-image-or-other-serialised-form) on this topic, I've tried to display generated SVG like this:

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.toSvg(item.signature,600,20)}" escape="false"/>
```

Problem is still the same, I can't resize the SVG

**Update (solution):**
To use `viewBox` attribute

```
public String toSvg(..)
{
  .. 
  sb.append(String.format("<svg width=\"%d\" height=\"%d\" viewBox=\"0 0 %d %d\" preserveAspectRatio=\"xMinYMin meet\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\">\n", width/10, height/10, width, height));
  ..
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would convert the signature to an SVG (or PNG) which allows you to easily scale it down for displaying using CSS.

See also:

- [How to convert p:signature value to an image (or other serialised form)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42762362/how-to-convert-psignature-value-to-an-image-or-other-serialised-form)
- https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/8_0/#/components/signature?id=convert-to-binary

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to do that without physical storing SVG/PNG files? Problem is that it will be hundreds of thousands of signatures...

Comment: You can simply only do the conversion in your bean, right?

Comment: I must do conversion, save it to some location and display the PNG file smaller in the data table. It will work and maybe it's real solution.. I'm doing it right now :-)

Comment: You don't need to store the bytes in a file, you can serve them from your bean.

Comment: Oh, thank you, but, to be honest, I'm not sure how at this moment.. how to set correct output stream

Comment: If you go for SVG you can simply embed it in your XHTML.

Comment: I can display SVG (`<h:outputText value="#{bean.toSvg(item.signature,60,20)}" />`), but I¨m not able to resize it, SVG behave exactly like original signature component, because it's not an image : /

Comment: SVG and viewBox helped me. Thank you! `sb.append(String.format("<svg width=\"%d\" height=\"%d\" viewBox=\"0 0 %d %d\" preserveAspectRatio=\"xMinYMin meet\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\">\n", width/10, height/10, width, height));`